# Adjust scroll view insets not working properly on iOS 10 and bellow

Tags: ios, xcode

I checked the `Adjust Scroll View Insets` property in storyboard and pinned the tableview to fit its superview.

When I run the app on iOS versions bellow 10, the `tableView` gets covered by the `navigation bar` and the `tab bar`. But it works perfectly on iOS 11.

What am I missing?

P.S. I'm using xcode 9

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem just by adding the following code:

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    resultsController.tableView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
} else {
    resultsController.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = true
}
```